# How does "config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb" work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Specifically...

I don't understand how in a *new* Rails 5.2 app, if you enter the console and check `Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_protect_from_forgery` it'll return `true`

...but an *upgraded* Rails 5.2 app, if you enter the console and check `Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_protect_from_forgery` it'll return `nil` (unless you've manually set in `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb`)

[This GitHub comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29742#issuecomment-360143609) mentions this behavior, but I don't understand how this works & I haven't been able to find any documentation yet.

**WIP Update:** [This issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28291) seems like the point where it was decided to not include `new_framework_defaults*` files in newly generated apps. Then [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28469) mentions that `new_framework_defaults_*` files are only kept on a rolling basis. I'm still looking into why/how...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To load the defaults (i.e `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb`) in Rails 5.2, make the following change in `application.rb`

```
config.load_defaults 5.2
```

Then remove `new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb` from initializers

Comment: This is still surprisingly poorly documented. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

The boilerplate in the file itself explains how to use it:

```
# This file contains migration options to ease your Rails 5.2 upgrade.
#
# Once upgraded flip defaults one by one to migrate to the new default.
#
# Read the Guide for Upgrading Ruby on Rails for more info on each option.
```

You should *not*, as other replies have suggested, (1) Set `config.load_defaults` to the current Rails version programmatically, or (2) Change the `config.load_defaults` value *and then* delete the `new_framework_defaults_*.rb` file.

Instead, take the incremental approach suggested by the framework maintainers: flip the values in the `new_framework_defaults` file, test your application, and update the `config.load_defaults` value only once you've determined nothing has been broken by the changes in defaults.

A slightly faster approach if you're feeling impatient: enable them all and test your application. If anything breaks, bisection-search through the config settings in the `new_framework_defaults` file to find the subset of config default-changes that have broken your application.

Once you've determined your application is running smoothly with the new defaults, you can delete the `new_framework_defaults` file.

Answer (score -2):

```
config.load_defaults Rails::VERSION::STRING.to_f
```

will solve the problem forever )